# Does Sefer HaChinuch draw on some other source for the idea that one who does not learn Torah is like a beheimah (domestic livestock/cattle)?

Tags: sefer-hachinuch

In Sefer HaChinuch, in Mitzvah 419, Talmud Torah, the author says:
שרש מצוה זו ידוע, כי בלמוד, ידע האדם דרכי השם יתברך, וזולתו לא ידע ולא יבין, ונחשב כבהמה.

Is he relying on an earlier source for the idea that someone who does not learn Torah is considered like a beheimah? Does the Rambam say this somewhere?

Also - do any later sources discuss or elaborate on this specific simile?

Comment: ואני בער ולא אדע בהמות הייתי עמך